# What is the correct way to find and set the primary key generically with EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, primary-key

I am trying to access the primary key from a generic parameter on my entity class which is what all of my DB object inhert from.

The following code works. **But is it bad practise to access the DBcontext from within the Entity class?** If so, how else can I do this? Is there something like **IObjectContextAdapter** from EF6?

```
public abstract class Entity
    {
        private DBContext _context = new DBContext(null);

        [NotMapped]
        public int ID
        {
            get
            {
                return _context.PrimaryKeyValueInt(this);
            }
            set
            {
                _context.PrimaryKeyProperty(this).PropertyInfo.SetValue(this, value);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why not just do `entity.ID = 99;`? Please describe the problem more precise.

Comment: I am asking if it has a performance hit to acess the DBContext like this, or if there is a way to open it without getting to the database itself. I just need to be able to access the structure

Comment: Creating the DB context every time an entity is instantiated is indeed a performance killer. Also depends on your constructor implementation.

Comment: So how would I access this without instantiating DBContext?

Answer (score 0):

So, I assume you have a bunch of entity classes with various names for their primary keys, like `DoodadId`, `WidgetId`, etc. and want them all to extend a base class with a single property to access the primary key? If so, I've done something like that with Attributes and Reflection. Create an Attribute to use to identify Primary Key properties:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class EntityIdAttribute : Attribute
{

}
```

Then create the base class and add the property to it. In my case I use `Guid` for primary keys:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual Guid EntityId
    {
        get
        {
            return (Guid)EntityIdProperty.GetValue(this);
        }
        set
        {
            EntityIdProperty.SetValue(this, value);
        }
    }

    private PropertyInfo EntityIdProperty => this.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(EntityIdAttribute)))
                .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Then in your entity classes, extend `Entity` and decorate the primary key property with `[EntityId]`:

```
public class Widget : Entity
{
    [EntityId]
    public Guid WidgetId { get; set; }
    // ......
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Valuator. I had thought about doing this, I was hoping there would be an option to be able to pull it from the BDcontext, is there anyway to instaniate the structure of the DBContext without all the overhead?

Comment: Is there something like **IObjectContextAdapter** from EF6?